# Не могу установить пакеты Python

Tags: python, pycharm, импорт, package

Я пытаюсь установить пакеты Python, но мне выдает ошибку "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл"

Пытался установить как через командную строку "pip install" так и в самом PyCharm

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Дополните пожалуйста, какую именно команду вы вводите.

Comment: В командной строке ввожу "pip install pytelegrambotapi" 
В PyCharm просто через настройки пытаюсь добавить новую библиотеку, любую

Comment: Наверное путь к pip нужно добавить в PATH?

Comment: Или перейти в каталог с pip.

Comment: Вы при установке Python отмечали галочкой "Добавить в Path"?

Comment: Добавлял Pip в path